# Progress Dialog in Android with some background logic gives Handler Error?

Tags: android, handler, progressdialog

Anybody has any idea about ProgressDialog of Andorid with Thread? I am successfully able to display the dialog and dismiss it also, but I have some long logic to be done and then only to dismiss the dialog, until that dialog will display loading message. I put my logic code inside the Run method of thread with While condition that until I didn't get particular result it will run the code. But somehow it is giving Handler and `Looper.prepare()` error. I try to found this and get to know that I have to use the functionality of Handler class.

Comment: can you post your code please ?

Comment: .. and the related stacktraces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the same, you can implement [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) concept, and which is very much preferable in Android to implement threading task, by implementing this task, system itself handles the threading task like start, run, stop....etc. and that's why its known as as [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

If you have gone through [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) link then i am sure you have noticed those 4 methods of AsyncTask.

For your problem, you can implement the AsyncTask as below:

1. onPreExecute() - Display progress dialog
2. doInBackground() - implement all the long running task
3. onPostExecute() - dismiss progress dialog by calling `dialog.dismiss();`

I am sure you got it now.

All the best.

### Update:

you just need to write Dialog.Show() method inside the onPreExecute() method, and dialog.dismiss() inside the onPostExecute() method. And yes i have told 1000 times that you can't write Toast directly inside the doInBackground() method because Android doesn't allows to ride on the main thread, and if you still want to execute it then write the same Toast message inside the runOnUiThead method (this method should be inside the doInBackground().

Comment: Hello Chirag Raval, First of all thanks a lot for your quick response. I am pasting my code here for your review.

Comment: public class CurrentPositionTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
  protected void onPreExecute() {
   super.onPreExecute();
   setCriteria();
   progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
   progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
   progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
   progressDialog.show();
  }
  protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Helllo.....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   return null;
  }
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   super.onPostExecute(result);
   progressDialog.dismiss();
  }
 }

Comment: Its not formating code line by line.. I am sorry its not even readable.. I am just displaying Toast in doInBackground(), but its giving error of Looper.loop and Handler even i am not using it...

Comment: Thanks a lot Paresh Mayani.. I am doing the same thing and tackling with it and trying to get desired output. By the way thanks for your help and support it is very helpful...

Comment: Hello Paresh, i tried out your suggestion of AsyncTask. I would like to tell you that its running fine for ProgressBar but not for Dialog. Do you why is so? I try to track this and get to know that Dialog is UI component and need to handle using handler. Can you please suggest me how to solve out this problem. I simply show a Toast then it displays with Bar but not Dialogs. Please help if you have any idea. Thanks for your help....

Comment: @Scorpion you just need to write Dialog.Show() method inside the onPreExecute() method, and dialog.dismiss() inside the onPostExecute() method. And yes i have told 1000 times that you can't write Toast directly inside the doInBackground() method because Android doesn't allows to ride on the main thread, and if you still want to execute it then write the same Toast message inside the runOnUiThead method (this method should be inside the doInBackground().

Comment: @Scorpion For more info, i was telling such as http://stackoverflow.com/q/8241540/379693 to write inside the `doInBackground()` method.

Answer (score 1):

ProgressDialog comes under UserInterface.Donot dissmis it inside thread and show before starting thread;

like this.

```
 Thread th=new Thread(this);
 ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(this);
 pd.setMessage("Loading...");
 pd.show();
 th.start();
```

Now take handler class to dismiss it

```
void run(){
 ///do your work;
 handler.sendEmptyMessage(0); 
 }
 private Handler  handler=new Handler(){
   //override onhandle message method and dismiss dialog in it

  }
```

Comment: any problem then ask.IF it solved your problem then accept it as answer

Comment: Thank you Tofeeq for your quick and kind response. I will try this and hope that my problem will be solved.. Thanks again..

Comment: Hello Tofeeq it is still giving me the handler error..

11-19 20:37:55.140: E/AndroidRuntime(279):at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-19 20:37:55.140: E/AndroidRuntime(279):at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-19 20:37:55.140: E/AndroidRuntime(279):at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-19 20:37:55.140: E/AndroidRuntime(279):at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

Comment: android.os.Looper.loop Exception means you are updating UserInterface task e.g-Setting text to TextView or setting image to ImageView etc.So do not do this in thread do this in handler class.

Comment: Tofeeq, no its not solved yet. Its still giving the handler error. Its also saying about WindowManager, as ProgressDialog is UI component that's why it is giving me the error. I tried ProgressBar instead of Dialog and its running absolutely fine, but that's not what i want to do. I'm still trying to solve it out.

Comment: I got the solution Tofeeq. Thanks for your help and valuable time.