# Run thread from another thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I test the following code and the Toast message did not appear and the "TestMethod" did not call "Catch" method  , please help me ?

```
public void TestMethod()
 {
     Test= new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             try{
                Catch(); 
             }
             catch (Exception ioe) 
             {

             }

         }
     });
     Test.start();
 }
public void Catch()
 {
     Test2= new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             try{
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
             catch (Exception ioe) 
             {

             }

         }
     });
     Test2.start();
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a toast **only from the UI Thread**. If you have access to the activity, you can change your code like thi

```
public void TestMethod()
 {
     Test= new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             try{
                Catch(); 
             }
             catch (Exception ioe) 
             {

             }

         }
     });
     Test.start();
 }
public void Catch()
 {
     activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             try{
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
             catch (Exception ioe) 
             {

             }

         }
     });

 }
```

Answer (score 6):

May be [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) helpful to you.

- runOnUiThread lets you ride on the UI thread and let s you to perform action on UI thread.

Try this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
{
      public void run() 
      { 
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
      }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You should call `Toast.makeText` on UI thread. Read [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

This is the complete solution and it should work perfectly
Some methods will only run on the uithread, (runOnUiThread is a method on the activity, so if you can't reach it, than just put a variable

```
private final Activity activity = this;
```

and call the runOnUiThread from there

```
 public void TestMethod() {
 Test= new Thread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         try{
            Catch(); 
         }
         catch (Exception ioe) {
            //always log your exceptions
            Log.e("simpleclassname", ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
         }
     }
 });
 Test.start();
}
public void Catch() {
    Test2= new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try{
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() { 
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              });
         catch (Exception ioe) {
            //always log your exceptions
            Log.e("simpleclassname", ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
         }

     }
 });
 Test2.start();
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The thread you are using does not allows toast to show. You must do UI related stuff on a UI thread. If you are not on Main Thread, then you need to use runOnUiThread.